# How to setup DMZ in router with DD-WRT firmware?

Tags: ssh, httpd, dmz, dd-wrt

I have a router d-link dir-300, flashed to dd-wrt v24. By the unknwon reasons web interface not working. 
Spawning in console httpd, didnt help.
Now I need a DMZ ip. 
How I can setup it with standard ssh session?

Comment: This site is for programming questions!

Answer (score 0):

This might get more coverage on ServerFault.

However, the preferred way to do this is through the web interface. I assume that you tried going to 192.168.1.1 for your router's web interface and tried to use the interface there. The below link recommends checking iptables if you can't access it for some reason.

http://www.dd-wrt.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=514123&sid=0403a15d614b80819514b22de0e74528

To answer your actual question, you can set the dmz related variables that are located here:

http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Factory_Defaults

Comment: Ok, thank. My nvram looks like: `root@hellgate:~# nvram show | grep dmz
dmz_enable=1
size: 28578 bytes (36958 left)
dmz_ipaddr=2
root@hellgate:~# `. DMZ ip is 10.0.0.3. I cant find, what I must set in nvram dmz_ipaddr for correct work. Any advices?

Comment: If the web interface don't work, you can't assume that the rest of the DD-WRT image is working correctly either-  Abandon this and get a fully working DD-WRT install on your router before you waste any more time with this broken DD-WRT installation.